# Why is it that answers almost always get more upvotes than questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've noticed that almost every single question asked by anyone has fewer votes than its subsequent answers. For example, in [my recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269220/to-what-extent-do-crewmembers-have-privacy-when-cleaning-themselves-on-federatio?noredirect=1#comment742821_269220), my question has 6 upvotes and the highest-upvoted answer has 12, exactly twice as many.

What is the cause of this phenomenon?

Comment: The knowledge is contained in the answer; not the question. Also I think a lot of people just forget to upvote questions.

Comment: What Carrot said, and also quite often there's a lot more work in the answer than in the question, and people reward that.

Comment: OP spent about two minutes writing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204999/does-any-looney-tunes-character-ever-use-any-fictional-brand-name-product-that-i) and I spent about two hours answering it. Who deserves more upvotes?

Comment: I almost just upvoted their question without upvoting your answer >: )

Comment: I think there’s another thing going on. Let’s 10% of questions and answers are popular enough to get 20 upvotes or more. One question may have 3-10 answers. That would mean that if you looked at ten questions with answers, you’d find only 1 question with 20 or more upvotes but maybe 3-10 answers with 20 or more upvotes. Also the high scoring answers are more visible. Point being, it might just be that higher scored answers are more visible, even if the percent of answers with high scores is similar to questions. Maybe someone can write a query to compare average question vs answer scores.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Not sure if it works properly cos I’ve phoned it in but [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1670013/average-post-scores) might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Huh. If you wrote it right and I’m reading it right, looks like questions get upvoted slightly *more* than answers on average? But I guess questions are very likely to have lower scores than their top answers.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think so but that’s just a base average. Would probably be worthwhile removing outliers, different averages etc. but I’m not bothering to do that on my phone!

Comment: You're not making HNQs. They tend to be terribly overrated. Q. demanding more specialistic knowledge tend to be less upvoted.

Comment: Ironically enough, on the occasions that I see a good answer getting less votes than an equally good question, I feel like the answer should deserve more recognition.

Comment: Per internet code, we must now always ensure the post in question has an answer with twice as many upvotes as the question.